# Composite build: get parent plugin version

Tags: gradle, configuration, composite

I have primary project `A` and included project `B`.
Both projects apply the same plugin `P`.
And I need in project `B` apply plugin `P` of the same version, as project `A`.
In `A` settings.gradle.kts:

```
pluginManagement {
  plugins {
    id("P") version "1" apply false
  }
}

includeBuild("B")
```

In `B` settings.gradle.kts:

```
pluginManagement {
  plugins {
    val ver = "Need as in A, i.e. 1"
    id("P") version ver apply false
  }
}
```

I tried to use `gradle.parent.pluginManager.findPlugin("P")` in `B` settings.gradle.kts, but it returns `null` (suppose because it has not been applyed yet).
May be I need wait until `A` will finish configuration, but action in `gradle.parent.settingsEvaluated` never called in `B`.

Is it possible access parent's plugins at all?

Comment: I think you are fighting Gradle trying to do it that way. Especially with plugins which have severe limitations on when and how they are manipulated. Better to declare the version of the plugin somewhere in the primary project (eg a version catalog (https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/platforms.html)) and pick it up from there